# Returns a new linked list node filled in with the given order?

Tags: c, algorithm

I am working on a project which requires me to make a newNode and allocate that node with the order. I am not sure if I am doing it correctly. Also, how can I make a test case for this function to test the code I have written?

```
/*
Returns a new linked list node filled in with the given order, The function
 * allocates a new order and copy the values stored in data then allocate a 
 * linked list node. If you are implementing this function make sure that you
 * duplicate, as the original data may be modified by the calling function.
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "list.h"

struct order 
{
        int id;
        char side;
        int quantity;
        double price;
};

struct onode 
{
        struct order* data;
        struct onode* next;
        struct onode* prev;
};

struct onode* newNode (struct order* data)
{
    struct order* dataValue  = (struct order*) malloc(sizeof(struct order));
    struct onode* linkedlist = (struct onode*) malloc(sizeof(struct onode));

    *dataValue = *data;

    linkedlist ->data = dataValue;

    linkedlist->data->id = dataValue->id;
    linkedlist->data->price = dataValue->price;
    linkedlist->data->quantity = dataValue->quantity;
    linkedlist->data->side = dataValue->side;
    linkedlist->next->prev = NULL;

    return linkedlist;

}
```

Also, is this efficient? What else can I change to make this program better?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15328644/905902 exact duplicate?

Comment: `If you are implementing this function make sure that you * duplicate, as the original data may be modified by the calling function.` 

For this, use memcpy to copy the contents of data into dataValue. By doing `*dataValue = *data;` you are just making dataValue point to data.

Comment: @RBK: `*dataValue = *data;` is fine. doing `dataValue = data` would be bad.

Comment: Oh yes, my bad. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @wildplasser i am new to this website, that is my code as well. i thought of making a new question will help. 
@RBK&@wildplasser, is my code rite? except the memcpy ?

Comment: your question is being answered elsewhere.